# Why won't Python webbrowser module work properly?

Tags: python, python-webbrowser

Ok, some background info: I'm using the most recent version of Python 3 and Visual Studio Code. I'm on the most recent version of Windows 10 and all of my browsers are up to date.

I've been trying to use the `webbrowser()` module of Python, but it gives me this: `AttributeError: module 'webbrowser' has no attribute 'open'` When I have this in the code: `webbrowser.open("https://docs.google.com/slides", new=1)`

What do I with this? I understand that it means that "open" doesn't exist, but it worked about a month ago. Was there an update to the module?

Comment: Have you named a script of your own `webbrowser.py`?

Comment: Ah, I see the problem. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just so everyone knows: If you're importing a module into python, don't name a separate file as the same name as the module.(Ex: webbrowser.py, random.py, math.py)